# Как в Qt получить доступ к свойству кнопки?

Tags: c++, qt

Извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, но как в Qt получить доступ к свойству кнопки?

В Qt не работает код, который работает в WPF/Winforms:

```
void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    stopButton.enabled = true;
}
```

Говорит, что элемент `stopButton` не объявлен (это имя кнопки на форме класса `MainWindow`).

Нагуглил такое `stopButton->enabled (true)`, но тоже не работает.

Comment: Непонятно только зачем, при нажатии, включать и так включенную кнопку.

Comment: Это я просто пока осваиваюсь, как что работает. Первый день в Qt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все обращения к графическим объектам на форме происходит через указатель `ui`, поэтому:

```
void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    ui->stopButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 2):

Собственно при работе в QtCreator можно задать один из трех видов агрегации формы ui (Параметры-С++-Создание класса Qt):

1. Через указатель (обращение ui->stopButton)
2. Просто агрегация (обращение ui.stopButton)
3. Множественное наследование (обращение stopButton)

Прямого доступа к свойствам тоже нет. Для каждого свойства существуют функции для чтения и записи, как те же setEnabled/isEnabled